# mysql get amount value of maximum date

Tags: mysql

I have table A like this:

```
mydate       kodetb   amount
-----------------------------
2016-03-10   203      600
2016-03-11   203      100
2016-03-11   200      110
```

and i have table B like this

```
kodetb  service  
---------------
200     ok
203     not ok
```

i want to display result like this:

```
kodetb   mydate     amount    service
--------------------------------------
200     2016-03-11  110       ok
203     2016-03-10  100       not ok
```

where second line result 100 displayed because it has LATEST/biggest date

pls help

Comment: In the result, for `kodetb = 203` date should be `2016-03-11`right??

Answer (score 0):

Below query works fine. I have tested it on my local, it is giving the desired output.

```
SELECT tableA.kodetb,mydate,amount,service
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.kodetb = tableB.kodetb
GROUP BY tableA.kodetb
HAVING MAX(mydate);
```

In your table data WHERE condition is also not needed. But it will be required for matching data when non matched data is also present in the tables.

Comment: This is incorrect, it does not show the latest transaction date.

Comment: It is showing the latest. I have tested here on my local machine

Comment: Can you place a reason why it will not show the latest date

Comment: You have to have all of your `select` columns that are not used in an aggregate function in your `group by` statement to do it the way you are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **<kbd>JOIN</kbd>** and **<kbd>NOT EXISTS</kbd>**.

**Query**

```
select t1.kodetb, t1.mydate, t1.amount, t2.service
from tableA t1
join tableB t2
on t1.kodetb = t2.kodetb
where not exists(
    select 1 from  tableA t
    where t.kodetb = t1.kodetb
    and t.mydate > t1.mydate
)
order by t1.kodetb;
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a84c0/1)</kbd>**

Comment: This works, but correlated sub-queries are not as efficient as joins.  I prefer joins for this kind of thing.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated sub-query, but these are notoriously inefficient.

This way works with a join, you have to use a table alias to identify records that do not have a greater value (that's what the `left outer` does here).  This trick gives you a `NULL` for c.mydate if it is the greatest value:

```
SELECT a.kodetb, a.mydate, a.amount, b.service
FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.kodetb = b.kodetb
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA c ON c.kodetb = a.kodetb AND c.mydate > a.mydate
WHERE c.mydate IS NULL
```

Here is a fiddle showing the results:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3faee/16

This is a tricky query, because when you use an "aggregate" like `MAX` (or `SUM` or `AVG` or whatever) you have to `GROUP BY` all the other columns in your select.  So, if you `SELECT MAX(xdate), name, service FROM table` you get an error, because `xdate` is an "aggregate" and you do not `group by` columns `name` and `service`

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
select tablea.kodetb, mydate, amount, tableb.service 
from tablea 
inner join tableb on tablea.kodetb = tableb.kodetb 
order by mydate desc
```

Comment: This is incorrect, it shows 3 results and should only show 2